# Bootstrap datepicker show dates only

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

Is it possible to show only dates in [Bootstrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ?

I am showing only months and years using following methods -

```
$("#year").datepicker({
    format: " yyyy", 
    viewMode: "years",
    minViewMode: "years"
});

$("#month").datepicker({
    format: " mm", 
    viewMode: "months",
    minViewMode: "months",
    maxViewMode: 0
});
```

A live [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ni8mr/0Lyjou4s/) showing only year and month selection in **Year** and **Month** field. I want to show only date from 1 to 31 without Month, Year at the top and also without day's name, at the **Date** field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but a bit complicated, you have to:

- Set the [`format`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format) option to `d` (or `dd`)
- Set [`maxViewMode`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#maxviewmode) option to `0` (`minViewMode` is `0` by default)
- Hide prev/next month buttons and the month name button, you can do it using CSS:

  - the *days view* of the datepicker is inside a table that has `.datepicker-days` class
  - the prev and next button are inside the `.datepicker-days` table and they have `.prev` and `.next` classes
  - the month name is in the same table and it has the `.datepicker-switch` class
- The date datepicker should show the right number of days, so you have to dinamically update [`defaultViewDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#defaultviewdate) when year and month are selected (see [`changeDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate) event)

  - Since the picker has no setter method for `defaultViewDate`, you can [`destroy`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#destroy) it and then re-init it.

Here a full working sample:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dateOpt = {
    format: 'dd',
    maxViewMode: 0
  };
  
  $("#year").datepicker({
    format: "yyyy",
    viewMode: "years",
    minViewMode: "years"
  }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
    var month = $('#month').datepicker('getDate');
    if( !month ){
      month = new Date();
    }
    dateOpt.defaultViewDate = {
      year: e.date.getFullYear(),
      month: month.getMonth(),
      day: 1
    };
    // Reset date datepicker
    $('#date').datepicker('destroy');
    // Re-init with defaultViewDate option
    $('#date').datepicker(dateOpt);
  });

  $("#month").datepicker({
    format: "mm",
    viewMode: "months",
    minViewMode: "months",
    maxViewMode: 0
  }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
    var year = $('#year').datepicker('getDate');
    if( !year ){
      year = new Date();
    }
    dateOpt.defaultViewDate = {
      year: year.getFullYear(),
      month: e.date.getMonth(),
      day: 1
    };
    $('#date').datepicker('destroy');
    $('#date').datepicker(dateOpt);
  });

  $("#date").datepicker(dateOpt)
});
```

```css
/* Hide prev/next buttons and month name*/
.datepicker-days>table>thead>tr>th.prev,
.datepicker-days>table>thead>tr>th.datepicker-switch,
.datepicker-days>table>thead>tr>th.next {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide days of previous month */
td.old.day{
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* Hide days of next month */
td.new.day{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="form-control-label col-md-3" for="year">Year</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <input type="text" id="year" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="form-control-label col-md-3" for="year">Month</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <input type="text" id="month" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="form-control-label col-md-3" for="year">Date</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <input type="text" id="date" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ! The explanation is very helpful .